# Mobilefirst migrating database kinds

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any instructions on migrating databases, say Oracle to Db2.
Is it just creating the tables in DB2 then exporting table info from oracle and inserting them to DB2

MobileFirst 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database administrators should be able to do this either manually or using tools/utilities.

Some of the tools/links that show up in a search on the topic are:

a) [IBM® Database Conversion Workbench](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communitystart?communityUuid=05901c97-75b2-47a1-9c32-25f748855913)

b) [Database Migration from Oracle to DB2 - IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/form/anonymous/api/library/4c93d906-7036-4f26-b7fd-1f0eb778fdb7/document/64b3274b-6fab-4abf-aef3-c69c1a3e6aff/media)

c) [Oracle to DB2 Conversion Guide: Compatibility Made Easy](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247736.html)

d) [Move data using the IBM DB2 Migration Toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0411yip/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vivin, but be aware that the changes required to the server configuration must be carefully reviewed and tested in order for the system to operate properly.  You'll also need to change the JDBC driver.